# Hyperledger Fabric CA server - getting error while initializing BCCSP PKCS11 library

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hyperledger-fabric, hsm

I have created HSM on demand service for Hyperledger Fabric offered by Thales.

1. Created HSM service using the Thales portal.
2. Created HSM client using which we connect to the HSM service created.
3. Updated the bccsp section in fabric-ca-server config file with below details.

   ```
       default: PKCS11
       pkcs11:
           Library: =/etc/hyperledger/fabric/dpod/org1.example.com/libs/64/libCryptoki2.so
           Pin: "*****"
           Label: testhsm
           hash: SHA2
           security: 256
           Immutable: false
           filekeystore:
               # The directory used for the software file-based keystore
               keystore: msp/keystore
   ```
4. sourced the setenv file which has come with HSM client zip using the command `source ./setenv`
5. started the fabric-ca-server as native process using `fabric-ca-server start`  - the server could successfully connect to HSM service.
6. Tried starting the fabric-ca-server in a docker container , volume mounted the entire HSM client zip, andthe $ChrystokiConfigurationPath was set.

While starting the fabric ca server docker container it throws below error `Error: Failed to get BCCSP with opts: Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11: Failed initializing PKCS11 library =/etc/hyperledger/fabric/dpod/org1.example.com/libs/64/libCryptoki2.so testhsm: Instantiate failed [=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/dpod/org1.example.com/libs/64/libCryptoki2.so]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an `=` sign in your bccsp config:

```
Library: =/etc/hyperledger/fabric/dpod/org1.example.com/libs/64/libCryptoki2.so
```

should be

```
Library: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/dpod/org1.example.com/libs/64/libCryptoki2.so
```

Answer (score 0):

yes that was one of the issue.

The main issue was resolved by:

- Modifying the fabric-ca docker file, it currently uses Alpine as base image, HSM fails to initialize on Alpine, replaced this with centos.
- Rebuilt the fabric-ca images and started the fabric-ca-server.